# Create helper for render handlebars using php

Tags: php, handlebars.js, php-5.3, handlebarshelper

I have a big problem and I don't understand how to solve this.
So I have a class for helper :

```
class IfCondHelper implements HelperInterface
{
public function execute(Template $template, HandlebarsContent $context, $args, $source)
{
    $parsed_args = $template->parseArguments($args);

    if (count($parsed_args) != 3) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            '"IfCond" helper expects exactly three arguments.'
        );
    }

    switch ($context->get($parsed_args[1])) {
        case "==":
            return ($context->get($parsed_args[0]) == $context->get($parsed_args[2])) ? $source : false;
            break;
..............
     }
}
```

Now in my template I do :

```
{{#ifCond 2 '==' 2}} {{data.oUser.number}} {{/ifCond}}
```

The problem is that the template doesn't show the value of `data.oUser.number` whitch is 4 but show the code `data.oUser.number` whitout interprete them. The helper works fine, because if I do :

```
{{#ifCond 2 '==' 2}} <p>Test</p> {{/ifCond}}
```

This works fine. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, need to do a supplimentaire render after call the helper

```
return ($context->get($parsed_args[0]) == $context->get($parsed_args[2])) ? $template->render($context) : false;
```